# How to print locally changed global variable outside the local?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    let i=1;  

    $('#add').click(function(){  
      i++;
      console.log("Inside: " + i);
    });  

    console.log("Outside: " + i);
</script>
```

While I will click on `add` then both will change. Inside and Outside. Now only inside value is changing. I know why it is happening. Just I want to know the why how can I change it in locally and globally.

Comment: The "inside" code only runs when the "click" event  happens, and it runs *every time* there is a "click". The "outside" code only runs once, when the `<script>` is initially evaluated.

Comment: Yes. but it's a global variable. I want to know by any how while I will change the local variable which is actually globally declared, I will get the update from globally.

Comment: @kaziRaushan It _is_ updated. You just never log `i` after it has been updated.

Comment: *"both will change"* .... There is no *"both"*. There is only *one* variable `i`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this ..

```
let i = 1;
let number;
const addBox = document.querySelector("#add");

addBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
  updateFromOutside();
});

function updateFromOutside() {
  console.log(`Updating from outside ${i}`);
}
```

Calling `updateFromOutside()` function from inside which `console.log()` the `i` variable of global scope.